# UIWebView unable to run JavaScript as document.getElementById returns null

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview, getelementbyid

I am currently trying to run a few bits of JS within my webView to simply fill out a few text fields on a 3rd party site. This has so far been successful on other sites but I seem to be getting issues with a specific url.

```
 let loadFirstNameJS = "var inputFields = document.getElementById('Field1'); inputFields.value = '\(firstName)';"
 self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadFirstNameJS)
```

Executing the JS to input a string value (firstName) has previously been simple. However I can't seem to access the element 'Field1' as it looks as though it doesn't exist? (returning a null value) even though I am able to view and edit within a browser.

It was my understanding that a UIWebView doesn't excuse any JS until the page has fully loaded so assume it can't be a problem of trying to access the element before it is created.

Here is the html of the specific Field1 I am trying to edit.

```
<li id="fo134li1" class="notranslate leftHalf     ">
<label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">
    First Name
            <span id="req_1" class="req">*</span>
        </label>
<div>
    <input id="Field1" name="Field1" type="text" class="field text medium" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="2" onkeyup="handleInput(this); " onchange="handleInput(this);" required="">
        </div>
</li>
```

This is one of the last things that I need to work out before my project is completed, so any assistance as to why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really track the page loading and not run the javascript until you see the page finish loading. You are probably executing it too quickly.

You can detect the start of a load by implementing

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

and detect the end by implementing

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

or detect errors by implementing

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

You need to keep track of how many loads start and finish since some pages can load other pages. When all pages have finished, run your javascript.

Comment: apologies, should've mentioned that the 'self.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadFirstNameJS)' above is all being executed within 'func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)'

I've implemented a small println() in all 3 methods above and my console log confirms no errors, and the page starts & finishes loading.

Testing this with other web sites I know complete the text fields, I am not getting any console log of finish loading.

Comment: Can you load the URL with Safari and run the JS in the web inspector console? If so then it is most likely your code. If not then use the web inspector to debug. I take it there is no authentication for this URL, as UIWebView does not handle any of that for you?

Comment: Thanks Rory, it looks as though the elements I am trying to access are located within an iframe (explains why it wasn't as simple as initially thought). The strange thing is, the frame requesting access has a protocol of http: but the frame being accessed has a protocol of https, so Safari is blocking this when trying to access the iframes content/window where the text fields are with my JS.